# How to get only XML content from a SOAP response

Tags: java, xml, soap, jdom

I have a sample response:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <soapenv:Header/>
    <soapenv:Body>
        <trk:TrackResponse xmlns:trk="somens1">
            <common:Response xmlns:common="somens2">
                <common:ResponseStatus>
                    <common:Code>1</common:Code>
                    <common:Description>Success</common:Description>
                </common:ResponseStatus>
                <common:TransactionReference>
                    <common:CustomerContext>Sample Response</common:CustomerContext>
                </common:TransactionReference>
            </common:Response>

        </trk:TrackResponse>
    </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

I want to remove the `Envelope`, `Header` and `Body` tags and use only the xml beginning from `TrackResponse`.

I am trying to traverse the response using `jdom`.

```
   Element body = jdom.getRootElement().getChild("Body", Namespace.getNamespace("http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"));
```

I actually need a jdom `Document` object retrieved from the jdom `Element` starting from `TrackResponse`.

Solution or better alternatives?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With your `body` content retrieved with:

```
Element body = jdom.getRootElement().getChild("Body", Namespace.getNamespace("http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"));
```

Do:

```
Namespace trk = Namespace.getNamespace("somens1");
Element response = body.getChild("TrackResponse", trk);
response.detach();
Document doc = new Document(response);
```

This will create a new document with the `trk` prefixed namespace and the `TrackResponse` at the root. The `detach()` is required when moving an element from one location (parent) to another.